# Open access publication fee

Tags: funding

I am a young resercher from bangladesh. I have submitted a muniscript to SPGbiomed and the articale has been accepted. Now I have to pay the APC (article processing charge). Is there any grant who can provide the charge on behalf of the author?

Comment: Did you search for a sponsor or grant before submitting? Did you check with your supervisor? Did you check if there are other places to publish without fees?

Comment: I strongly suggest that you check out [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/17379/7734), [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/83764/7734), and finally [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/26455/7734) question.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the number of spam emails I've gotten from them, the google autofills after "Science Publishing Group" being both scam and predatory before anything else, the fact that all of the actual search results say it's a scam, and that [this article by Jeffrey Beall](https://www.4open-sciences.org/articles/fopen/full_html/2018/01/fopen180001s/fopen180001s.html) calls them out by name... it's pretty unlikely that anyone would give you money to publish there.

You could ask them to waive the APC but I don't know why a predatory journal would do that - it seems to be counter to their purposes. I guess worth a try though, provided you are amenable to publishing in a predatory journal.

Comment: *I don't know why a predatory journal would do that - it seems to be counter to their purposes. I guess worth a try though.* – Even then, you gain nothing. Your paper would still be published in a predatory journal.

Comment: Well to me (and also to you, I'm assuming) that's less than nothing. There are other people who would benefit from the line on their CV, and sometimes they'd benefit a lot. I don't want to come out and tell someone in a different situation then me that they shouldn't ever do this thing and they're bad for doing it. With that said, if I found out anyone in my department had published in a predatory journal I would probably never stop ridiculing them.

Comment: I won’t debate this (simply because this is not a good place to do this), but you should at least add a disclaimer. “I guess worth a try though” could be read as if there is no problem with predatory journals except for their price – which is far from the truth.

Comment: That's fair enough

Answer (score 1):

Check with your professor or university librarian. They are the ones most likely to know. If they don't, assume the answer is "no".

You could conceivably ask for a waiver or discount based on your status as an author from a developing country, as well.

Comment: Some universities may be willing to pay such fees. And some journals will waive them when they fall to the author. Or at least they did in the past, though publishing has changed somewhat.

Comment: That's why - ask your university librarian.

Comment: The department head might also be good. Funding, if available, might not come via the library.

Comment: Libraries do fund APCs at least in Germany and the rest of Europe but not for predatory journals.