# What to do in case of academic dishonesty by organizers after getting published

Tags: ethics

I am trying to avoid academic dishonesty as far as possible. I have submitted a paper to a local journal and after getting published, I noticed that the editor-in-chief (who is also a professor in a university in my country) has added three of his papers in the citations. He did not even bother to reference them in the content of the paper.
My topic is related to deep learning in plant disease and the references he added are related to radio transmission systems, deep learning in skin, and video quality streaming.
At that time I let it go because to whom should I complain with him being the editor in chief of that journal? He did the same with other papers published in his journals and is still doing it.
Should I ask the same person to withdraw my paper, though it has been a year since I got it published? Would it be considered misconduct on my part, if I do nothing?

**Note** Editor in chief has 85 citations in his top 12 most cited papers from the journal he managed.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83764/how-do-i-identify-predatory-and-low-quality-journals-with-bealls-list-gone-ho

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do if I submitted an article to a predatory journal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26455/what-should-i-do-if-i-submitted-an-article-to-a-predatory-journal)

Comment: I think doing nothing is acceptable.  The best answer might depend on who the publisher is; some publishers would fire the editor if they found out.  Others would look away.

Comment: I don't think this journal is predatory, except this everything is good. They have a good review process, they don't accept every paper. They don't have very high APC.